# Excel formula countif for 3rd condition

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formula, countif

I am having working formula for 2 conditions and I need 3 condition to be added

`IF(COUNTIF(M12:M34,"FAIL")>0,"FAIL","PASS")`

Now I need to look at cells from ***M12 to M34*** and if all the cells are blank, then add **3rd condition "NOTRUN"**

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using `COUNTIFS`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another **IF** Formula at the beginning to add your 3rd condition. 
So you would end up with:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(M12:M34,"")=ROWS(M12:M34),"NOTRUN",IF(COUNTIF(M12:M34,"FAIL")>0,"FAIL","PASS"))
```

In general when you need to add several conditions, you can always simply add an If condition in the "Value if True" or "Value if False" from your first If formula which would give you something as below:

```
If(A=1,"Result A",If(A=2,"Result B", IF(A=3,"Result C","No Result")))
```